# Can I disable Test Mode after installing unsigned drivers?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, drivers, display-driver

I set some unsigned video drivers to install with my system by disabling checks for signing. A Test Mode watermark and build number are displaying.

Is it safe to disable Test Mode now that they're installed? If so, how do I safely go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you disable the Test mode again, the driver will fail to load if the driver is unsigned. So, no it is not safe to disable the Test Mode in your case.